# Fetch dial number while calling.

Tags: android, phone-number

When I enter any number in keypad and after when I press call button before the phone make call, I want to get that dial number in logcat.

See below Image for understand.

[image]

Can I get the number at the time of calling, if yes then How can I?

Comment: Try overriding the **Call** button on keypress event