# Is there any way at all to end a call in Android post 2.3?

Tags: android, telephony

I'm trying to develop something similar to AutoAnswer but it also auto hangs up when a broadcast receiver is notified.  I've spent all day reading other stackoverflow question on this issue and it seems that the permission `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is restricted to System Apps, however, some posts said that using endCall(); does not require this permission.

**My question has two parts**:

1. Is `endCall()` still usable?  Has it ever been used anywhere in any case since Android 2.3?
2. If it is, I need help making it work because right now it's not working.  I download `ITelephony.aidl` from http://code.google.com/p/autoanswer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/#com/android/internal/telephony
   and put it in a package.  I'm a new user so I can't post images.

This is what my file tree looks like in netbeans:
[image]

And this is the code thats running in my broadcastreceiver.  It's been posted numerous times here before as a solution to this problem yet I still can't get it to work :/

```
    ITelephony telephonyService;
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
        telephonyService.endCall();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: some exception handling
    }
```

Looking through the logs, I see this error:

```
[PhoneIntfMgr] CMD_END_CALL: no call to hang up
```

EDIT: I'm brand new to android development and can't seem to find the console output for android apps - like for a call to e.printStackTrace() but I did have Toast display some text inside the catch block like this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "IN CATCH BLOCK ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       toast.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But nothing shows up on the screen..

Comment: With the state of your code you can't tell if an exception was thrown or not. Maybe for started you should add some debugging output to your catch block.

Comment: Hope it Helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860369/fetch-dial-number-while-calling

Comment: First learn about logcat.  Then think about why you want to hang up the user's phone on them - that's very rarely an appropriate thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    /* your code */
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "OFFHOOK",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setResultData(null);
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    /* your code */
                    break;
                }
                // super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }

        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

When you are going to OFFHOOK state, you can see a toast that show "OFFHOOK" and then `setResultData(null);` is end the call.

Comment: Will this code work once the call is already in progress?  I do not want to block calls, I want to end current calls.

Comment: see edited post, it's detected call states. I'm using OFFHOOK State for end call, it's when you accept call or when you enter a number and dial

Comment: Thanks! I will try this tomorrow morning.

Comment: I tried this and the toast message shows up on the screen but the call never ends.