# How to create a ghost mode like app?

Tags: android

I have an android app that needs to hide and only appear when the user dials a specific number. Can I please know exactly how it is done? I have searched and no success. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860369/fetch-dial-number-while-calling.

Comment: ok I was able to hide the app and then launch it by the dialpad, but after i launch it the icon shows again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide the app completely from the launcher, you need first to create a BroadcastReciever:

```
   public class LaunchAppViaDialReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (null == bundle)
        return;
    String phoneNubmer = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    //here change the number to your desired number
    if (phoneNubmer.equals("<Requested Number>")) {
        setResultData(null);
        if(status == true){
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context,
                    YourLauncherActivity.class);
            packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(context,    YourLauncherActivity.class);
            appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(appIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And add the Permission: android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
Add the BroadcastReciever to the Manifest File.

It is Preferable to make the user set the Ghost mode via preferences