# How to get the number, From number pad before dialing In android

Tags: java, android, phone-call, calllog

I search every where for this ..i didn't get it any where please help me..
How can i get the number from number pad before dialing ..[image]

I just want when number pad number count will be 11 or 12 digit .. I just want a toast message showing the number.. Thats it..

I have some idea to get it.. Like as we are typing any new number it's detecting that number is a new one or a existing one.. I am getting the number when i am dialing the number , But i want like, When i am entering any number upto 12 digit it will popup a toast of that number.. So .. please any one help me..

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860369/fetch-dial-number-while-calling

Comment: I tried @user2025187 But it's fetching the number after i pressed diled button.. Which i have done previously .. So any other idea ??